# Trying to get property of non-object laravel 5.3 (Auth class)

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use laravel 5.3 package. I add my package service provider on `config/app.php` and it work correctly. but when I use `auth` on package controller show me error
I am login and on other controllers work correctly. on laravel 5.2 work correctly. but on 5.3 show me error

My controller :

```
     public function index()
     {

          return Auth::user()->name;
     }
```

Error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
in TestController.php line 115
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\wamp64php\www\test\modules\Test\Controller\TestController.php', '115', array()) in TestController.php line 115
at TestController->index()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(TestController), 'index'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('index', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(TestController), 'index') in Route.php line 190
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 642
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 644
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 618
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Comment: ```Auth::user()->name``` is only accessible if you are logged in, you must check first if you are logged in before using what code.

Comment: Is the user logged in? `Auth::user()` should be null at this point

Comment: First of all, ensure your package has `auth` middleware and second of all... `Auth::user()` is **null** here thats why you are having this error

Comment: Try `dd(auth()->user());` before the `return Auth::user()->name;` in your controller method and see what it outputs. If there is no logged in user it will dump `null` else it will dump the currently logged in user (model instance).

Comment: @prateekkathal Thanks .

Comment: @Donkarnash  I solved it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it
Add this middelware on kernel.php

```
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

Comment: I've been struggling for this for hours and I don't understand why they don't put something as simple as this, including documentation. Thanks dude!